# Remove "Empty rows" from Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I created an demo application based on the reference of Android Developers' Training "NotePad" tutorial.

[The completed Tutorial can be referenced from here](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/notepad-ex3.html)

I admit that I am new in this section and really needs to learn a lot about Listviews and SQLite database.

My problem is that in the notepad, I am getting empty rows when I enter nothing in the title and/or body sections as in shown figure,
[image: notepad working Screen]

so, I have a function to delete the row by clicking on the textview present in list, eg., "cool" in the above section.

The reference is working nice when we enter title into the body. If we just save and/or press back button with entering TITLE, I am resulting in the empty rows above and below as shown in the above picture.

Any one who have gone through this tutorial or having some idea of about how to delete/ remove or make a reference to deletion of empty rows, Please suggest me.

Thank You.

Comment: Mind posting the code snippets here?

Comment: Can you plz check the above link, as it will be more clear than posting all the code here.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to remove() the item from your adapter object and then just run the notifyDatasetChanged() on the Adapter, any ListViews will (should) recycle and update on it's own.

Comment: But, I am referring/populating the listView from database, so it will become tough. As remove() can remove the item referred from an Array or ArrayList , I think!